# Flutter Fade Image with Decoration Image

Tags: image, flutter, dart

I want to use FadeInImage with DecorationImage
but i get this error 
type 'FadeInImage' is not a subtype of type 'ImageProvider'

```
        Container(
                width: 150.0,
                height: 150.0,
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        image: _storedImage == null
                            ? authProvider.user.photoId != null
                                ? FadeInImage(
                                    image: NetworkImage(apiUrl +
                                        "appauth/get-image/" +
                                        authProvider.user.photoId),
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                    placeholder: AssetImage(
                                        'assets/images/avatar.jpg'),
                                  )
                                : AssetImage('assets/images/avatar.jpg')
                            : FileImage(
                                _storedImage,
                              ),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                     )
```

Comment: Please add the full error stack trace. What line is the error refering to?

Comment: FadeInImage(
                                    image: NetworkImage(apiUrl +
                                        "appauth/get-image/" +
                                        authProvider.user.photoId),
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                    placeholder: AssetImage(
                                        'assets/images/avatar.jpg'),
                                  )

Comment: You can't use `FadeInImage` in `DecorationImage`. The original post linked in the title, should give you a workaround how to achieve it. If you think your question isn't the duplicate, feel free to comment, I'd be happy to reopen it.

Comment: ``FadeInImage`` is type of Widget and inside ``DecorationImage`` image parameter is type of ``ImageProvider``, that's why you can not use in ``DecorationImage``.